# Include XMLHttpRequest before transpiling typescript code using webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, webpack, aws-lambda

Currently, I am developing a lambda function using Typescript and transpiling to Javascript using `webpack` and `bable-loader`.

The transpilation works as expected and I get an Index.js file that I can upload to Lambda. However when I run the Lambda function I get the following error:

```
NetworkingError: XMLHttpRequest is not defined
```

I have read that node doesn't have all the build-in Javascript browser functions, so I need to add this package =>`https://www.npmjs.com/package/xmlhttprequest`

And I add it to my project in this way:

```
var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
```

But I still have the same problem. I am almost sure this is because XMLHttpRequest is being called from the dependencies that are being added to the Index.js file. So I think it is necessary to include the XMLHttpRequest module before the transpilation starts.

this is my webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './lib/index.ts',
  output: {
    filename: 'index.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
  target: 'node',
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
    alias: {
      'XMLHttpRequest': path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules/xmlhttprequest')
    }
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { 
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        options: {
          presets: [
            [
              '@babel/preset-env',
              {
                targets: {
                  node: true,
                },
              },
            ],
            '@babel/preset-typescript',
          ],
        },
      },
    ],
  },

};
```

I am not sure if this is the correct way to resolve the XMLHttpRequest module

```
alias: {
          'XMLHttpRequest': path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules/xmlhttprequest')
        }
```

I would really appreciate, if someone could help me to solve out this problem.

Comment: have you found any solution yet ?

Comment: Hey @NickChanAbdullah, for me this line of code did the trick `global.XMLHttpRequest = require('xmlhttprequest').default;`